# Solving a third order non-homogeneous ODE $x^{3}y'''-2x^{2}y''-17xy'-7y=45x^{2}lnx-24x^{2}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following non-homogeneous differential equation?
$$x^{3}y'''-2x^{2}y''-17xy'-7y=45x^{2}lnx-24x^{2}$$ and $y(1)=1,y'(1)=0,y''(1)=0$

I'm stuck finding out the homogeneous solution. I got 3 solutions for the D-operator. $(D-1)(D^{2}+7)$. How should I compute my homogeneous and particular solution with this equation?

Comment: Does the particular solution start as $\frac{1}{(D-1)(D^{2}+7)}45ze^{2z}-24e^{2z}$?

Comment: The D operator is not correct Sanit

Answer (score 1):

The factorization should be $$f(D)=(D+1)^2(D-7)$$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is therefore:
$$\implies y_h=\frac {c_1}x+c_2\frac {\ln x}x+c_3x^7$$
And the particular solution for the DE:
$${(D+1)^2(D-7)}y=  e^{2t}(45t-24))$$
Try undetermined coefficients method with this guess:
$$y_p=e^{2t}(At+B)$$

---

For the operator:
$$y_p= \dfrac 1 {(D+1)^2(D-7)}  e^{2t}(45t-24))$$
$$y_p= e^{2t}\dfrac 1 {(D+3)^2(D-5)}  (45t-24))$$
$$y_p= e^{2t}\dfrac 1 {(-45-21D+......)}  (45t-24))$$
$$y_p=\dfrac {- e^{2t}}{45}\dfrac 1 {(1-(-7D/15)+......)}  (45t-24))$$
$$y_p=\dfrac {- e^{2t}}{45}(1-7D/15+......)  (45t-24))$$
$$y_p=\dfrac {- e^{2t}}{45}(45t-24-21) $$
$$y_p=- e^{2t}(t-1) $$
Unsubstitute $t=\ln x$
$$\boxed { y_p=x^2(1-\ln x)}$$
Finally the answer is:
$$\boxed { y(x)=\frac {c_1}x+c_2\frac {\ln x}x+c_3x^7+x^2(1-\ln x )}$$

Comment: When working out the particular solution, can I write it as $e^{2z}\frac{1}{D^{3}}45z-24$?

Comment: @Santi no you can't do this here

Comment: Then for $y(x)$ equation should I just add the homogeneous solution and the particular solution?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. Then equation $y(x)$ would get too complicated to find out $c_1, c_2, c_3$ right?

Comment: Can you use undetermined coefficients method  ? It's more simple here @Santi

Comment: That's the one about guessing first the solution right?

Comment: Yeah where you try $y_p=e^{2t}(at+b)$ @Santi

Comment: I added a full answer with the D operator @Santi

Comment: I tried and got the same values. However, isn't this part $(1-(-\frac{7D}{15})+.....)$ just $(1-(\frac{-7D}{15})+.....)$?

Comment: @Santi check your calculation again expand correctly the operator I have  $-30D+9D=-21D$ then factorize $-45$ it has then a plus sign....

Comment: Final solution would be $y=\frac{2}{67x}-\frac{51}{67}\frac{lnx}{x}-\frac{2}{67}x^{7}+x^{2}(1-lnx)$

Comment: @Santi  with initial conditions yes